# Регулярные выражения на C#

Tags: c#

У меня есть алфавит {a,b,c}. Для него нужно составить регулярное выражение по предложению "Произвольная цепочка символов a, b и c, заканчивающаяся символами сс".
По идее это `(a|b|c)*(cc)`
Но проверка через `Regex.IsMatch` выводит мне и слова, начинающиеся с `cc`

```
using System; 
using System.Text.RegularExpressions; 
 
class Program 
{ 
    static char[] alphabet = { 'a', 'b', 'c' }; 
    static List<string> GenerateWords(int n) 
    { 
        List<string> words = new(); 
        int alphabetSize = alphabet.Length; 
        int[] indices = new int[n]; 
 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        { 
            // Convert index to base-alphabet and append corresponding letters 
            string word = ""; 
            int index = i; 
            while (index > 0) 
            { 
                int remainder = index % alphabetSize; 
                word = alphabet[remainder] + word; 
                index /= alphabetSize; 
            } 
            while (word.Length < 1) 
            { 
                word = alphabet[0] + word; 
            } 
            Console.WriteLine(word); 
            words.Add(word); 
        } 
        return words; 
    } 
    static void FindRegex(List<string> words, string finalChars) 
    { 
        string regex = "("; 
        for (int i= 0;i<alphabet.Length;i++) 
        { 
            regex += alphabet[i]; 
            if (i != alphabet.Length - 1) regex += '|'; 
        } 
        regex += ")*(" + finalChars+')'; 
        Console.WriteLine("Regular expression: " + regex); 
 
        List<string> matchingWords = new List<string>(); 
        foreach (string word in words) 
        { 
            if (Regex.IsMatch(word, regex)) 
            { 
                matchingWords.Add(word); 
            } 
        } 
        if (matchingWords.Count == 0) Console.WriteLine("Words not found or final symbols are not contained in this alphabet"); 
        else 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Matching words: "); 
            foreach (string word in matchingWords) 
            { 
                Console.WriteLine(word); 
            } 
        } 
        
 
    } 
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        List<string> words= GenerateWords(30); 
        FindRegex(words, "cc");   
    }  
}
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

В регулярном выражении не указано, что не может быть других символов.

Таким образом выбранные строки вполне подходят под выражение: пустая последовательность `a|b|c` после которой идет `cc`.

Для исправления достаточно указать `$` который сопоставляется с концом строки, чтобы явно указать, что `cc` должны быть именно у конца строки.

Также можно добавить `^`, для указания что и спереди ничего не должно быть

```
^(a|b|c)*cc$
```

---

небольшое отступление: цикл

```
for (int i= 0;i<alphabet.Length;i++) 
{ 
    regex += alphabet[i]; 
    if (i != alphabet.Length - 1) regex += '|'; 
}
```

Легко меняется на [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-7.0): `string.Join("|", alphabet)`

И общая сборка выражения упрощается до:

```
regex = `({string.Join("|", alphabet)})*{finalChars}`;
```

Comment: А не должно ли регулярное выражение выглядеть так: `^(a|b|c)+(cc)$` ? То есть, если не указать для группы обязательность вхождения, то под совпадение попадает строка `cc` , что конечно заканчивается на `cc`, но перед собой никаких символов не содержит: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uVOBk4

Comment: @XelaNimed, здесь все упирается в то, как понимать _произвольная цепочка_. Обычно такая цепочка может состоять из 0 символов. Но это просто вопрос терминологии

Comment: Согласен. В вопросе этот момент упущен.

Comment: А в C# нельзя написать `^[abc]+cc$` ?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, можно

Comment: Просто от выражения `(a|b|c)` мой перфекционизм очень страдает 

Comment: А ещё фраза «у меня есть алфавит» обычно подразумевает, что никаких других символов не бывает, так что выражение можно сократить до `.cc$` (или `cc$` если разрешён пустой префикс) 

Comment: @AlexeyTen, это все опять упирается в то, как понимать задачу :)

Comment: Это да, а автор куда-то пропал…